# iOS Monotouch - How to set Frame before ViewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to set the Frame before ViewDidLoad() in a UIViewController?

Currently, I do this in the constructor:

```
View.Frame = _frame;
```

The problem is that this call automatically triggers first the ViewDidLoad() function.
In ViewDidLoad() I place my subviews dependant on the "View.Frame" property.

But this property only changes after ViewDidLoad() was completed.
So basically "View.Frame = _frame;" first trigger "ViewDidLoad()" with the old "Frame" value and only after that the property is changed.

I can solve this by first assigning a class variable to "_frame" and use that in "ViewDidLoad()", but I would like to see if there is another solution and if I'm missing something here.
(I'm also missing the idea behind this flow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common situation on iOS, and I would say you are doing the right thing for your constructor. Calling the getter on the `View` property will load the view, so they provide an `IsViewLoaded` property to check for this.

If it is not a constructor where you are passing in the frame, you could also do something like this in your controller:

```
public void SetFrame(Frame frame)
{
    if (IsViewLoaded) {
        View.Frame = frame;
    else {
        _frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Because of this scenario, it might be worth thinking about your design. I don't know the full situation, but could your controller decide its `Frame` within the class? Maybe you could pass another value in that would let you do the math for `Frame` in `ViewDidLoad`, and that would match Apple's pattern a little better.